# How to Programmatically place order in opencart

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I am new to opencart. And now i am working on the order module.The concept is i have to place order externally. So as in the controller/checkout/confirm.php order placement i have placed the order. The order also successfully stored at the order table. But the problem is, the order is not shown at the admin page. I have searched lot for this issue, finally i found that the order is not placed properly. 
My code is,

```
public function index() {
        $redirect = '';
        $this->load->model('account/address');
        $address = $this->model_account_address->getAddress($this->customer->getAddressId());
       if ((!$this->cart->hasProducts() && empty($this->session->data['vouchers'])) || (!$this->cart->hasStock() && !$this->config->get('config_stock_checkout'))) {
            $redirect = $this->url->link('checkout/cart');
        }

        // Validate minimum quantity requirements.
        $products = $this->cart->getProducts();

        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $product_total = 0;

            foreach ($products as $product_2) {
                if ($product_2['product_id'] == $product['product_id']) {
                    $product_total += $product_2['quantity'];
                }
            }

            if ($product['minimum'] > $product_total) {
                $redirect = $this->url->link('checkout/cart');

                break;
            }
        }

        if (!$redirect) {
            $order_data = array();

            $order_data['totals'] = array();
            $total = 0;
            $taxes = $this->cart->getTaxes();

            $this->load->model('extension/extension');

            $sort_order = array();

            $results = $this->model_extension_extension->getExtensions('total');

            foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
                $sort_order[$key] = $this->config->get($value['code'] . '_sort_order');
            }

            array_multisort($sort_order, SORT_ASC, $results);

            foreach ($results as $result) {
                if ($this->config->get($result['code'] . '_status')) {
                    $this->load->model('total/' . $result['code']);

                    $this->{'model_total_' . $result['code']}->getTotal($order_data['totals'], $total, $taxes);
                }
            }

            $sort_order = array();

            foreach ($order_data['totals'] as $key => $value) {
                $sort_order[$key] = $value['sort_order'];
            }

            array_multisort($sort_order, SORT_ASC, $order_data['totals']);

            $this->load->language('checkout/checkout');

            $order_data['invoice_prefix'] = $this->config->get('config_invoice_prefix');
            $order_data['store_id'] = $this->config->get('config_store_id');
            $order_data['store_name'] = $this->config->get('config_name');

            if ($order_data['store_id']) {
                $order_data['store_url'] = $this->config->get('config_url');
            } else {
                $order_data['store_url'] = HTTP_SERVER;
            }

            if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
                $this->load->model('account/customer');

                $customer_info = $this->model_account_customer->getCustomer($this->customer->getId());

                $order_data['customer_id'] = $this->customer->getId();
                $order_data['customer_group_id'] = $customer_info['customer_group_id'];
                $order_data['firstname'] = $customer_info['firstname'];
                $order_data['lastname'] = $customer_info['lastname'];
                $order_data['email'] = $customer_info['email'];
                $order_data['telephone'] = $customer_info['telephone'];
                $order_data['fax'] = $customer_info['fax'];
                $order_data['custom_field'] = unserialize($customer_info['custom_field']);
            } elseif (isset($this->session->data['guest'])) {
                $order_data['customer_id'] = 0;
                $order_data['customer_group_id'] = $this->session->data['guest']['customer_group_id'];
                $order_data['firstname'] = $this->session->data['guest']['firstname'];
                $order_data['lastname'] = $this->session->data['guest']['lastname'];
                $order_data['email'] = $this->session->data['guest']['email'];
                $order_data['telephone'] = $this->session->data['guest']['telephone'];
                $order_data['fax'] = $this->session->data['guest']['fax'];
                $order_data['custom_field'] = $this->session->data['guest']['custom_field'];
            }

            $order_data['payment_firstname'] = $address['firstname'];
            $order_data['payment_lastname'] = $address['lastname'];
            $order_data['payment_company'] = $address['company'];
            $order_data['payment_address_1'] = $address['address_1'];
            $order_data['payment_address_2'] = $address['address_2'];
            $order_data['payment_city'] = $address['city'];
            $order_data['payment_postcode'] = $address['postcode'];
            $order_data['payment_zone'] = $address['zone'];
            $order_data['payment_zone_id'] = $address['zone_id'];
            $order_data['payment_country'] = $address['country'];
            $order_data['payment_country_id'] = $address['country_id'];
            $order_data['payment_address_format'] = $address['address_format'];
            $order_data['payment_custom_field'] = $address['custom_field'];

            if (isset($this->session->data['payment_method']['title'])) {
                $order_data['payment_method'] = $this->session->data['payment_method']['title'];
            } else {
                $order_data['payment_method'] = '';
            }

            if (isset($this->session->data['payment_method']['code'])) {
                $order_data['payment_code'] = $this->session->data['payment_method']['code'];
            } else {
                $order_data['payment_code'] = '';
            }

            if ($this->cart->hasShipping()) {
                $order_data['shipping_firstname'] = $address['firstname'];
                $order_data['shipping_lastname'] = $address['lastname'];
                $order_data['shipping_company'] = $address['company'];
                $order_data['shipping_address_1'] = $address['address_1'];
                $order_data['shipping_address_2'] = $address['address_2'];
                $order_data['shipping_city'] = $address['city'];
                $order_data['shipping_postcode'] = $address['postcode'];
                $order_data['shipping_zone'] = $address['zone'];
                $order_data['shipping_zone_id'] = $address['zone_id'];
                $order_data['shipping_country'] = $address['country'];
                $order_data['shipping_country_id'] = $address['country_id'];
                $order_data['shipping_address_format'] = $address['address_format'];
                $order_data['shipping_custom_field'] = $address['custom_field'];

                if (isset($this->session->data['shipping_method']['title'])) {
                    $order_data['shipping_method'] = $this->session->data['shipping_method']['title'];
                } else {
                    $order_data['shipping_method'] = '';
                }

                if (isset($this->session->data['shipping_method']['code'])) {
                    $order_data['shipping_code'] = $this->session->data['shipping_method']['code'];
                } else {
                    $order_data['shipping_code'] = '';
                }
            } else {
                $order_data['shipping_firstname'] = '';
                $order_data['shipping_lastname'] = '';
                $order_data['shipping_company'] = '';
                $order_data['shipping_address_1'] = '';
                $order_data['shipping_address_2'] = '';
                $order_data['shipping_city'] = '';
                $order_data['shipping_postcode'] = '';
                $order_data['shipping_zone'] = '';
                $order_data['shipping_zone_id'] = '';
                $order_data['shipping_country'] = '';
                $order_data['shipping_country_id'] = '';
                $order_data['shipping_address_format'] = '';
                $order_data['shipping_custom_field'] = array();
                $order_data['shipping_method'] = '';
                $order_data['shipping_code'] = '';
            }

            $order_data['products'] = array();

            foreach ($this->cart->getProducts() as $product) {
                $option_data = array();

                foreach ($product['option'] as $option) {
                    $option_data[] = array(
                        'product_option_id'       => $option['product_option_id'],
                        'product_option_value_id' => $option['product_option_value_id'],
                        'option_id'               => $option['option_id'],
                        'option_value_id'         => $option['option_value_id'],
                        'name'                    => $option['name'],
                        'value'                   => $option['value'],
                        'type'                    => $option['type']
                    );
                }

                $order_data['products'][] = array(
                    'product_id' => $product['product_id'],
                    'name'       => $product['name'],
                    'model'      => $product['model'],
                    'option'     => $option_data,
                    'download'   => $product['download'],
                    'quantity'   => $product['quantity'],
                    'subtract'   => $product['subtract'],
                    'price'      => $product['price'],
                    'total'      => $product['total'],
                    'tax'        => $this->tax->getTax($product['price'], $product['tax_class_id']),
                    'reward'     => $product['reward']
                );
            }

            // Gift Voucher
            $order_data['vouchers'] = array();

            if (!empty($this->session->data['vouchers'])) {
                foreach ($this->session->data['vouchers'] as $voucher) {
                    $order_data['vouchers'][] = array(
                        'description'      => $voucher['description'],
                        'code'             => substr(md5(mt_rand()), 0, 10),
                        'to_name'          => $voucher['to_name'],
                        'to_email'         => $voucher['to_email'],
                        'from_name'        => $voucher['from_name'],
                        'from_email'       => $voucher['from_email'],
                        'voucher_theme_id' => $voucher['voucher_theme_id'],
                        'message'          => $voucher['message'],
                        'amount'           => $voucher['amount']
                    );
                }
            }

            $order_data['comment'] = "";
            $order_data['total'] = $total;

            if (isset($this->request->cookie['tracking'])) {
                $order_data['tracking'] = $this->request->cookie['tracking'];

                $subtotal = $this->cart->getSubTotal();

                // Affiliate
                $this->load->model('affiliate/affiliate');

                $affiliate_info = $this->model_affiliate_affiliate->getAffiliateByCode($this->request->cookie['tracking']);

                if ($affiliate_info) {
                    $order_data['affiliate_id'] = $affiliate_info['affiliate_id'];
                    $order_data['commission'] = ($subtotal / 100) * $affiliate_info['commission'];
                } else {
                    $order_data['affiliate_id'] = 0;
                    $order_data['commission'] = 0;
                }

                // Marketing
                $this->load->model('checkout/marketing');

                $marketing_info = $this->model_checkout_marketing->getMarketingByCode($this->request->cookie['tracking']);

                if ($marketing_info) {
                    $order_data['marketing_id'] = $marketing_info['marketing_id'];
                } else {
                    $order_data['marketing_id'] = 0;
                }
            } else {
                $order_data['affiliate_id'] = 0;
                $order_data['commission'] = 0;
                $order_data['marketing_id'] = 0;
                $order_data['tracking'] = '';
            }

            $order_data['language_id'] = $this->config->get('config_language_id');
            $order_data['currency_id'] = $this->currency->getId();
            $order_data['currency_code'] = $this->currency->getCode();
            $order_data['currency_value'] = $this->currency->getValue($this->currency->getCode());
            $order_data['ip'] = $this->request->server['REMOTE_ADDR'];

            if (!empty($this->request->server['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
                $order_data['forwarded_ip'] = $this->request->server['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
            } elseif (!empty($this->request->server['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
                $order_data['forwarded_ip'] = $this->request->server['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
            } else {
                $order_data['forwarded_ip'] = '';
            }

            if (isset($this->request->server['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
                $order_data['user_agent'] = $this->request->server['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
            } else {
                $order_data['user_agent'] = '';
            }

            if (isset($this->request->server['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])) {
                $order_data['accept_language'] = $this->request->server['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];
            } else {
                $order_data['accept_language'] = '';
            }

            $this->load->model('checkout/order');
            $this->session->data['order_id'] = $this->model_checkout_order->addOrder($order_data);

            $data['text_recurring_item'] = $this->language->get('text_recurring_item');
            $data['text_payment_recurring'] = $this->language->get('text_payment_recurring');

            $data['column_name'] = $this->language->get('column_name');
            $data['column_model'] = $this->language->get('column_model');
            $data['column_quantity'] = $this->language->get('column_quantity');
            $data['column_price'] = $this->language->get('column_price');
            $data['column_total'] = $this->language->get('column_total');

            $this->load->model('tool/upload');

            $data['products'] = array();

            foreach ($this->cart->getProducts() as $product) {
                $option_data = array();

                foreach ($product['option'] as $option) {
                    if ($option['type'] != 'file') {
                        $value = $option['value'];
                    } else {
                        $upload_info = $this->model_tool_upload->getUploadByCode($option['value']);

                        if ($upload_info) {
                            $value = $upload_info['name'];
                        } else {
                            $value = '';
                        }
                    }

                    $option_data[] = array(
                        'name'  => $option['name'],
                        'value' => (utf8_strlen($value) > 20 ? utf8_substr($value, 0, 20) . '..' : $value)
                    );
                }

                $recurring = '';

                if ($product['recurring']) {
                    $frequencies = array(
                        'day'        => $this->language->get('text_day'),
                        'week'       => $this->language->get('text_week'),
                        'semi_month' => $this->language->get('text_semi_month'),
                        'month'      => $this->language->get('text_month'),
                        'year'       => $this->language->get('text_year'),
                    );

                    if ($product['recurring']['trial']) {
                        $recurring = sprintf($this->language->get('text_trial_description'), $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product['recurring']['trial_price'] * $product['quantity'], $product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax'))), $product['recurring']['trial_cycle'], $frequencies[$product['recurring']['trial_frequency']], $product['recurring']['trial_duration']) . ' ';
                    }

                    if ($product['recurring']['duration']) {
                        $recurring .= sprintf($this->language->get('text_payment_description'), $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product['recurring']['price'] * $product['quantity'], $product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax'))), $product['recurring']['cycle'], $frequencies[$product['recurring']['frequency']], $product['recurring']['duration']);
                    } else {
                        $recurring .= sprintf($this->language->get('text_payment_cancel'), $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product['recurring']['price'] * $product['quantity'], $product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax'))), $product['recurring']['cycle'], $frequencies[$product['recurring']['frequency']], $product['recurring']['duration']);
                    }
                }

                $data['products'][] = array(
                    'key'        => $product['key'],
                    'product_id' => $product['product_id'],
                    'name'       => $product['name'],
                    'model'      => $product['model'],
                    'option'     => $option_data,
                    'recurring'  => $recurring,
                    'quantity'   => $product['quantity'],
                    'subtract'   => $product['subtract'],
                    'price'      => $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product['price'], $product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax'))),
                    'total'      => $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product['price'], $product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')) * $product['quantity']),
                    'href'       => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product['product_id']),
                );
            }

            // Gift Voucher
            $data['vouchers'] = array();

            if (!empty($this->session->data['vouchers'])) {
                foreach ($this->session->data['vouchers'] as $voucher) {
                    $data['vouchers'][] = array(
                        'description' => $voucher['description'],
                        'amount'      => $this->currency->format($voucher['amount'])
                    );
                }
            }

            $data['totals'] = array();

            foreach ($order_data['totals'] as $total) {
                $data['totals'][] = array(
                    'title' => $total['title'],
                    'text'  => $this->currency->format($total['value']),
                );
            }

            //$data['payment'] = $this->load->controller('payment/' . $this->session->data['payment_method']['code']);
        } else {
            $data['redirect'] = $redirect;
        }

        echo json_encode("success");

    }
```

Is this correct format or still any process to do like updating order table or etc...
I really don't know what to do next.. Please someone guide me to get rid of this issue..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Opencart admin display order which orders have order status is > 0. Did you check your order_status_id in database it will be 0.

That's the issue. How Opencart works, when you are at checkout - confirm page but you haven't confirm your order, Opencart already entered one entry for that order with order status id - 0.

After that when you confirm your order than your selected payment method - callback function (in mostly payment method(s)) update your order status using model > checkout > order function addOrderHistory().

So problem is that you added your order to Opencart but not updated it's order_status_id so after adding order add a function to your module with will update order status of last (or your added) order. For that you can check default payment methods.

Comment: I am using instamojo payment gateway but I have checked its callback function but it is giving error of invalid auth token

Comment: @RohitashvSinghal i think that's payment method error, you can ask payment company for support or can google error so that u will know reason.